# React leaflet upgraded to v4, this.ref returns null in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

Basically, I have leaflet map, showing a vehicle moving on it. now I have upgraded the leaflet v2 to v4. this.ref and  this.ref.leafletElement is undefined.
so, I am unable to animate the vehicle icon on map